# How to reference TFS work item when committing from Eclipse EGit or from git command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tfs

With the latest TFS Server and Eclipse with [TEE plugin (Team Explorer Everywhere)](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere)
how to reference TFS work item when [committing from within Eclipse](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-RU/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-eclipse)?

We would like to gradually switch from TFVS to Git, that is supported in TFS now.
But in Eclipse Commit dialog, there's no way select work item.
I guess it should be extended by TEE.

As subquestion, it would be awesome to use `git` command line for that as well.

Related: 2 years old [Reference TFS work item from code comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379103/reference-tfs-work-item-from-code-comment)

Comment: What's the detail  mean of reference ? Did you just want to associate Work Items to check-in in a Git enabled repository when using TEE plugin or git command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Team Service and TFS 2013 above, Git commits can be linked to work items. By adding a mention to the commit comment in the form of “#ID” where ID is the work item ID ,es #437.

[image]

More details info you can refer this blog: [Associate Work Items to check-in in a TF Service Git enabled repository](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/01/31/associate-work-items-to-check-in-in-a-tf-service-git-enabled-repository/)

Answer (score 1):

When you add `#1234` in the commit message they automatically get linked up to the work item. There is no pretty UI to find and associate the work items. That works both from the UI and from the git client e.g.:

```
git commit -m "Did some work fixed #1234"
```